# Writing multiple platform implementations in C++

Tags: c++, c, oop, operating-system, cross-platform

My goal is to write functions with different implementations per operating system.

Some projects do it this way:

```
system.h
system_win.cpp
system_osx.cpp
system_linux.cpp
etc...
```

Which makes sense. Then say you needed local variables that pertains to a certain OS, youd just create `system_win.h`. This technique would make your code very readable but would make managing the files to compile per OS very picky.

Then some projects heavily use `#ifdef`. The problem with this technique is the code could get very messy.

My source needs to be readable. But also needs to make sense.

What's best? And why?

Comment: Just a matter of opinion, ... mine is option 1. Its easy to get an IDE to handle files for you well.

Comment: I wouldn't make a header file for implementation-specific local variables. That's just asking for someone to include it in the wrong build. If they are local they should stay in the OS's implementation hidden from sight.

Answer (score 0):

You could create `system_win.h` for the user. And in `system.h`, use `#ifdef` to determine which OS user is using, and include the right header for them.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is operating in translation units. Many IDEs and build systems (even cross-platform ones) see your resulting app as a number of compilation units linked together. From your description you would like to build a `system` compilation unit. So

Make public interface header (no implementation details here, everything nice and clean). It contains public interface, visible to application being linked against it.

```
// system.h
int function_open(char*);
```

Make private implementation source

```
// system.cpp

int function_open(char*a)
{
#if defined(__MSWIN__)
  ::Create(a)
#elif defined(__OSX__)
  ::open(a)
#endif
}
```

> The problem with this technique (ifdefs) is the code could get very messy.

Some conditionals are a must. Whether you put them as ifdefs in your source or as some messy conditional compilation directives in your makefiles/meta-makefiles whatever.
In my practice, we try to maintain OS independence down to the lowest level of abstraction possible. We incapsulate OS dependence, so that no one else from other translation units need to see the actual implementation.

Choose your build system wisely (consider e.g. cmake). Depending on your build system other implementations may be possible (e.g. private and public headers physically reside in different places).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using platform-specific source files rather than `#ifdef`. As you say, it's the far more manageable approach.

If you need platform-specific header files, I find a good approach is to give them all the same filename but place them in separate platform-specific directories:

```
windows/abc/foo.hpp
linux/abc/foo.hpp
osx/abc/foo.hpp
```

Only the directories corresponding to your targeted platform would be added to the list of header search directories. You can then include the header as normal, and the correct one will automatically be chosen:

```
#include <abc/foo.hpp>
```

If you have some common code that you would like to share between platforms, you can instead create "private" platform-specific header files and make the "public" header common to all platforms:

```
windows/abc/detail/foo_platform.hpp
linux/abc/detail/foo_platform.hpp
osx/abc/detail/foo_platform.hpp
common/abc/foo.hpp
```

Then inside `foo.hpp`:

```
#include <abc/detail/foo_platform.hpp>
```